# Acumatica - Enable field in AP Bill while in Pending Approval status

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to enable the APTran.tranDesc field in the AP Bill Entry screen while the invoice is in the Pending Approval Status. I tried the below (which does not work)

```
public void APTran_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{

    APTran line = (APTran)e.Row;
    APInvoice invoice = Base.Document.Current;
    if (invoice == null || line == null || Base.IsExport) return;

   if (invoice.Status != APDocStatus.Open)
    {
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTran.tranDesc>(sender, line, true);
          

        }
}
```

I believe this is happening because of this line in APInvoiceEntry:

```
            Transactions.Cache.SetAllEditPermissions(allowEdit: false);
```

Is there an easy way to override just the one tranDesc field to allow the edit within the grid?

Comment: Did you check your Automation Steps ?

Comment: None of the automation steps on AP Bill are disabling fields plus to be sure - on my local - I deactivated all automation steps for the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
protected void APTran_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{      
  var row = (APTran)e.Row;
  if (row == null) return;
  APInvoice invoice = Base.Document.Current;
  if (invoice.Status == APDocStatus.PendingApproval)
  {
     cache.AllowUpdate = true;
     PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(cache, row, false);        
     PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTran.tranDesc>(cache, row, true);
  }      
}
```

you must enable cache for updating. disable all fields. then re-enable the field you want editable.

Comment: Thanks Rick. This makes perfect sense and works just like I needed it to.